# The following pseudo-code presents an algorithm to simulate rolling dice and count face numbers

Tags: python

The following pseudo-code presents an algorithm to simulate rolling dice and count face numbers.

0. start
1. initialize done to false
2. while not done

- prompt user to input a positive integer n
  if n is a positive integer
  set done to true
- otherwise
  output a meaningful error message
  prompt user to try input again

3. initialize a variable to store n number of integers (ex: rolling a die 30 times will store 30 different numbers)
4. loop n iterations, one for each roll of the die

- generate an integer between 1 and 6
- insert/append the generated integer to the storage variable

5. initialize a second storage variable to store counts of each number between 1-6 (how many times was each number rolled)
6. loop n or six iterations depending on the way you choose to code this assignment

- tally each generated integer (number rolled) in the first storage to corresponding count storage

7. output six counts (ex: 1 was rolled 7 times, 2 was rolled 4 times, 3 was rolled 6 times, etc.)
8. output percentage distribution (ex: 1 was 23.33% of rolls, 2 was 13.33% of rolls, 3 was 20.00% of rolls, etc.)
9. stop

I got the first part but do not get the rest of the part. Thanks!

```
#start() function to prompt user for a positive integer n with error checking and meaningful error messages.
  done = False
  while not done:
    #try reading integer input from user
    inputNumber = input('Enter a positive integer: ')
    try:#if input is positive, output the data.
      intInputNumber = int(inputNumber)
      if intInputNumber > 0:
        done = True
      else:#if input is not positive, display error and call this function again
        print("Please enter a positive integer. Try again!!")
    except ValueError:#if input is not integer, handle error
      print('Please enter an integer. Try again!!')
```

Comment: Are you asking us to write code for you?

Answer (score 0):

you can use python dictionary
like this

```
#initialisation
mydictionary={'1':0,'2':0,'3':0,'4':0,'5':0,'6':0}
```

then each time you get a valid input you do `mydictionary[inputNumber]+=1`